# sections and index in UITableView from Sqlite (FMDB)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, fmdb

I am trying to get the sections and index for `UITableView` from Sqlite (I am using FMDB as the wrapper). 
 I just can't seem to figure out where to start. 
I can read the information back from the DB and store it in a `NSMutableArray`.

I have tried the following site but he is using a plist.
http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/12/10/implementing-uitableview-sections-from-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us a small preview of your data model you would like to present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make an array of arrays. the main array will represent the tableview sections while the inner arrays will be the contents of the sections.

In the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` put

```
return [mainArray count];
```

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSMutableArray *tempDict = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *tempArray = [tempDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tempArray valueForKey:@"name"]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tempArray valueForKey:@"detail"]];
return cell;
```

p.s.the last object is a NSDictionary in my case, that's why I use `valueForKey`. Good luck!